# codeigniter reveal modal load once per session/cookie

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, modal-dialog

I have a modal window that loads on index page using the following command,

```
data-reveal-onready="Register"

$(document).ready(function () {
$('[data-reveal-onready]').reveal();
});
```

I want to add a php if statement on the data-reveal-onready to load only once per session on the homepage and when the user visits the homepage again it will not appear on load.

The modal is a registration form so obviously the modal window may be needed again and it will still show when clicking on register button.

I am using codeigniter and reveal modal.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps use CI's session class?

```
// Initialize on visit
$this->session->set_userdata('register_pop_up', true);

// Check
if ($this->session->userdata('register_pop_up'))
{
    // Don't display in the future
    $this->session->unset_userdata('register_pop_up');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use cookies to set the modal window. That way if a user comes to your site, gets the modal window, leaves and comes back before the cookie expiration, they will not get the modal window again.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/cookie_helper.html